# How to replace binary file during rpm upgrade without changing permissions

Tags: file-permissions, rpm, rpm-spec, file-ownership

I need to replace the existing binary during rpm upgrade but I do not want to change the permission/ownership which is set already.

In my case, after the binary installation (not upgrade), ownership/permissions are set properly by rpm. But after the rpm installation, permissions/ownership of the file are modified by admin to allow another process to run this binary. Owner/group of the another process is different from this process. But when the rpm is upgraded it resets the permissions/ownership and another process is now not able to execute it.

Looking for a solution on how to retain the existing ownership/permissions but replace the binary only.

Any type of help/pointers are appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the state of the file in `%pre` and restore it in `%posttrans` for more informations see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#Saving_state_between_scriptlets

Comment: Thank You. This is really helpful.